# Application incompatible with few devices

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my application on Google Play Store. I could search for it and install on almost every device. Except on [Samsung Galaxy Y Duos s6102](http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-y-duos-s6102/p/itmd6vvtrjwbgwgm#specifications)

After searching for a solution, few things i found out:

**Problem with uses-features in the Manifest:**

I am having only 2 features in the Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But the device has a Camera, so this might not be the case.

**Problem with support-screens in the Manifest:**

I haven't added any such tag in my Manifest, assuming that by default all Screens are supported. And confirmed that from the developer's console

[image]

I found out that **QVGA** Screens are not supported by default, you have to explicitly declare them.

But **QVGA** screens come under Small Screen as stated here:

[image]

Then thought density might be the reason, but from the docs:

```
For applications that support Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher, this is "true" by default and you should not set it "false"
```

So, are there any other reasons for this Issue? Or should i try adding them all to my Manifest file.

Comment: Your link lists the device as 'fixed focus' but your manifest has autofocus.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yeah, that is the only difference. So should i add `android:required="false"` to that tag??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes, unless your app has a barcode reader or some other feature which really needs autofocus.

Comment: whats the `minSDKVersion` of your app?? 10??

Comment: @MorrisonChang, you provided the correct answer. Please post it as an answer so it can be accepted and help future askers find the correct response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link provided to the device specifications, it states that the camera is 'fixed focus'.

When you add a `uses-feature` entry in your manifest, that feature is **required** and will block devices on Google Play which don't have it. As long as it doesn't break anything or make   features non-functional like a barcode scanner in the case of 'autofocus', adding `required=false` should be fine.